# React Native Router Flux Drawer

Tags: react-native

I am trying to change the state of my app when the drawer is opened.
onEnter and onOpen don't trigger at all.

I am using a custom NavBar so the hamburger button isn't being displayed but if i swipe left on my IOS device the drawer opens.

So how can i detect when the drawer is open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple choices!

1. Pass `this.props.open` and check this on `componentWillReceiveProps` and after that :

   `Actions.refresh({key: "drawer", open: true})`

   - Same issue is [here](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/2265)
   - Some more data that is good for your problem [here](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/3014)
   - Drawer in router flux provided by `React Navigation` so it's better that you see [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-based-navigation.html) documentation
   - react native router flux drawer added in v4 so maybe have a some bug now!
2. Use another drawer (I recommended to you [this](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#Drawer))

Comment: Hi Mohsen, the reason that i wanna detect when its opened and componentWillReceiveProps does just that is to set the global state. That just causes an infinite loop and crashes the app. How would i go about setting my global state on componentWillReceiveProps or should i just move on to step 2?

Comment: @AdrianLineweaver you can use `componentWillUpdate` to check if `this.props.open` changed or not and prevent from infinite loop!

Comment: Hi Mohsen can you clarify what im passing to the this.props.open?